# Using ansible, what is the best way to add a line to an existing file that depends on the value of a variable passed by --extra-vars?

Tags: ansible

I have a numerical config (e.g., number of milliseconds for some config) that needs to be set in a standard system file. I don't want to keep the whole config file in version control since it's part of a standard install. Is there a way to add a line to a file and have some variable replacement text in the line that can depend on a specified variable (e.g., passed via command line when the playbook is run using `--extra-vars`.

For example, something like the following (my best effort so far):

```
- name: Set ring delay
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
    state: present
    regexp: 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ring_delay_ms=.*"'
    line: 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ring_delay_ms=${ring_delay}"'
    backrefs: yes
  when: ring_delay is defined
```

where the playbook is executed with `ansible-playbook -e "ring_delay=10000"`
The above example works fine if I don't have variable value for the config (e.g., I just hard code `line: 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ring_delay_ms=10000"'`, but I would like to be able to specify the value manually from the command line when I run the playbook. Is there a good way to do this? Ideally, rerunning the playbook would overwrite the ring_delay with the new value

EDIT: From this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/gOCEbYX5yTc), It appears that the `${ring_delay}` notation I used above is not a feature of ansible, though there are a couple of examples on the web that suggest there is some related functionality for string replacement. The [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) refer to "named backreferences", but I'm not sure what those are.

Comment: What are all those '$' signs at EOLs ?

Comment: Oops, they are visible EOL characters in vim. Removing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax for interpolation is '{{ var }}'. The '${ var }' syntax has been deprecated for some time now.

Changing your task like below should do it :

`- name: Set ring delay
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
    state: present
    regexp: 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ring_delay_ms=.*"'
    line: 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ring_delay_ms={{ring_delay}}"'
  when: ring_delay is defined`

You don't need `backrefs` here since there are no catching groups in the regexp.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but only with `{{ring_delay}}`. However, it's not idempotent. A new line is added with each run of the playbook. Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The best solution I found was to insert a task to remove matching lines before this, which also takes care of removing the config when the playbook is rerun without the override specified. This is accomplished using `lineinfile` with the `regexp` option, taking care to escape the dollar sign, which matches the end of the line when used in a regexp.